# Determine Custom Conversion Action for AdSet in Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using the Facebook API Marketing API to get insight information about different ad campaigns. In the ad campaign insight results, there are a number of actions with values. When I look in the Facebook Ad Manager UI, I see the Result column for Campaigns where it shows me the value I'd like to extract from the API. The problem I'm running into is that I need to programmatically determine what action to pull the value from.

When I look in the AdSet settings in the UI, I see the Conversion Event which ties to a Custom Conversion but I don't know how to get that Custom Conversion ID for the ad set from the API.